# Is there any automation tool to verify data with ms excel sheet?

Tags: manual-testing

I have been assigned to verify posted data on a website developed on wordpress. Data has been posted manually through wordpress admin panel. I have given ms excel sheet and I have to verify every record from ms excel to website. There are near about 1000 records. It is really weird to verify all 1000 records one by one.

Is there any automation tool for this task?

Comment: If you know selenium webdriver and POI then it will be easy task for you.

Comment: Do you need to do this one time? Not sure automating is worth the time for a single compare run.

Comment: May be I need this again in another projects. So I am going to learn this. Thanks to all.

Comment: What does "verify" mean here? Do you mean that the data in each row of the spreadsheet exists in the same format on the website, and you just need to compare the two? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Exactly! I want .to compare spreadsheet data with the website. I need to compare both to check all data has been posted successfully

Comment: What programming language you're automating?

Answer (score 2):

You can use selenium and Java combination for this.

1. Create a Script which will read all the data from website.
2. Using Java POI API for reading data from excel, use this link for help http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/
3. Compare the data taken from selenium with excel.

Answer (score 1):

If u have knowledge of selenium then, 
you can use Selenium Webdriver with java.

Approach

1. Get the excel data using Apache POI
2. Get the data from website (which you are comparing) using driver.gettext() method with its element locator.
3. Use assert ,if/else or control structure to verify.

Comment: I will learn selenium webdriver with java, if it would help me to solve my problem. By the way, can you share some hints about how to verify 1000 records through selenium webdriver?

Comment: It isn't a very complex task, all need to do is write a Java code to loop till the last row, get required columns and keep comparing with visible text on Website.

Comment: @ JustARandomGuy if the person is well versed with language java i dont think it will be complex.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth considering [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)

This will allow for a fairly low learning curve to get you up and running.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.seleniumframework.com/data-driven-framework/data-drive-with-excel/) to use it in conjunction with excel

Although other tools are available which will accomplish the task, such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), the setup time may not prove beneficial in the scenario you describe.  But here is a tutorial if that is the direction you [choose](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/)

Comment: Just wondering, how Cucumber proves more beneficial in this scenario than Selenium ?

Comment: Selenium tends to have a larger setup time and for a small return, the investment in time might not be worth it on balance.  In a previous comment he has said he would learn Selenium and Java.  My feeling is that if he not from a programming background, then it will be easier to learn how to use a tool like Cucumber.

Comment: How Cucumber parses data from Web site?

Comment: If you have a seperate question about cucumber, raise a new question and people will be able to answer it for you

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what programming language you are familiar with, as selenium webdriver supports multiple interfaces.

Here is one of my suggestion: use Ruby + Selenium Webdriver.

1. Use Selenium Ruby API to grab text from the web page.
2. Use Ruby gem - spreadsheet API to grab data from the Excel.
3. Compare the data.

If you are not familiar with Selenium, I would suggest you to manually grab data from the web page and save it into a file, do the same thing to the Excel, and then open both files in notepad++, use notepad++ diff plugin to compare two files and you will be able to see the difference.